# Split amount into inputs passed

Tags: java

I have a requirement where I get totalAmount and how much parts to divide that amount into as inputs. For the outputresponse i am using builder pattern and also avoiding null fields.
Total amount is a big decimal (if null or less than 0, throw exception) and number of inputs can range between 1-3 (if outside of this range or non numeric, throw exception). I have written this code, but I am not convinced and think there may be a cleaner and better way that is also easy to understand just by looking at the code.
Also while splitting, whatever additional cents are left, that would be added to 1st amount.

eg. if 100.01 is total amount that i have to divide into 3 parts, i should get 33.35 for first amount and 33.33 for recurring amounts. Please advise if there is a cleaner and better way to achieve this.

```
public OutputResponse splitAmount(BigDecimal totalAmount, int divideInto) {
if (!(1 <= divideInto && 3 >= divideInto)) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        OutputResponse outputResponse;
        if (totalAmount != null && totalAmount.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) {
            BigDecimal recurringAmounts = null;
            BigDecimal firstAmount = totalAmount;
            if (divideInto > 1) {
                recurringAmounts = totalAmount.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(divideInto), 2, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
                firstAmount = totalAmount.subtract(recurringAmounts.multiply(new BigDecimal(divideInto - 1)));
            }

            outputResponse = OutputResponse.builder()
                    .firstAmt(firstAmount)
                    .secondPmtAmt(recurringAmounts)
                    .build();

            if (divideInto > 2) {
                outputResponse.setThirdPmtAmt(recurringAmounts);
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception();
        }
}
```

Comment: I feel https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better site for this question, Can you ask there ?

Comment: sure Deepak. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I liked the way you have defined the variable names, all the name gives clear idea about what it will store.  You are throwing generic exception, it can be a specific one, here the user gave wrong answer thus you could have thrown an InvalidRequestException or a custom one.

Comment: Does firstAmount and recurringAmounts differs ? If not then we can reuse the same variable

Comment: Yes Deepak, I am using custom exception. I just posted the generic one here to point more attention towards the logic. Also while splitting, whatever additional cents are left, that would be added to 1st amount. Thus the need for two separate variables. eg. if 100.01 is total amount that i have to divide into 3 parts, i should get 33.35 for first amount and 33.33 for recurring amounts.

Comment: I had one more doubt, if the value of `divideInto` is 1, then `recurringAmounts` and `firstAmount` both will equal `totalAmount`. And we will set the `secondPmtAmt` as `totalAmount`, but in this case the secondPmtAmt should be zero. This can be a issue, please point out if my observation is wrong.

Comment: No Deepak, according to this, recurring amount would only be set if divideInto > 1. BigDecimal recurringAmounts = null;
            BigDecimal firstAmount = totalAmount; only if divideInto > 1, then I am setting recurringAmount

Comment: Thanks user9150507, The code looks clean and good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be Optionals could help to make your code self-explanatory and avoid the nested if-else blocks:

```
public OutputResponse splitAmount(BigDecimal totalAmount, int divideInto) throws Exception {
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 3)
            .filter(x -> x == divideInto)
            .findAny()
            .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    
    Optional.ofNullable(totalAmount)
            .filter(d -> d.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0)
            .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    
    BigDecimal recurringAmounts = totalAmount.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(divideInto), 2, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
    BigDecimal rest = totalAmount.subtract(recurringAmounts.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(divideInto)));

    OutputResponse outputResponse = OutputResponse.builder();
    if(divideInto >= 1) {
       outputResponse = outputResponse.firstAmt(recurringAmounts.add(rest));
    }
    if(divideInto >= 2) {
       outputResponse = outputResponse.secondPmtAmt(recurringAmounts);
    }
    if(divideInto == 3) {
       outputResponse = outputResponse.setThirdPmtAmt(recurringAmounts);
    }
    
    return outputResponse.build();
}
```

If optionals do not suit your taste:

```
public OutputResponse splitAmount(BigDecimal totalAmount, int divideInto) throws Exception {
    if(divideInto < 1 || 3 < divideInto) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    
    if(totalAmount == null || totalAmount.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) <= 0) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    
    BigDecimal recurringAmounts = totalAmount.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(divideInto), 2, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
    BigDecimal rest = totalAmount.subtract(recurringAmounts.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(divideInto)));

    OutputResponse outputResponse = OutputResponse.builder();
    if(divideInto >= 1) {
       outputResponse = outputResponse.firstAmt(recurringAmounts.add(rest));
    }
    if(divideInto >= 2) {
       outputResponse = outputResponse.secondPmtAmt(recurringAmounts);
    }
    if(divideInto == 3) {
       outputResponse = outputResponse.setThirdPmtAmt(recurringAmounts);
    }
    
    return outputResponse.build();
}
```

Comment: Hey, @Eritean, Your solution looks very clean!!

Comment: Thanks @Eritrean, it looks good to me. However, one question in case I want to use some custom exception instead of IllegalArgumentException how can I do that? I am having one custom exception whose constructor accepts two parameters one is HTTP status code that I want to throw and another is CustomError object which contains two string for error details. Any idea if I can do that with optional?

Comment: @user9150507 Sorry for the delayed answer. I was not online for a couple of days. You should be able to throw your own exception as follows: `...orElseThrow(() -> new MyCustomException(HTTP_CODE, new CustomError("foo","bar"));`